# Why is Google Play Store popping up in my activity when I didn’t use it?

Tags: google-play-store

I check my Google Activity religiously and yesterday saw that it showed that I visited the Google Play Store three times at 2:19pm. Device Connected message also popped up at this time. I didn’t get on the Google play store though. Especially not three times. I even checked my device care and usage to see if it was opened and it wasn’t. No app updated in the background at that time either. So I’m really not sure why it’s showing I visited three times. I did open my phone at that time, but did not use the play store or any other app that I don’t normally use. Please help me understand.

Comment: Google Play Store manages Google Play Protect, which scans your device for harmful apps. It also puts apps into deep sleep when they have been unused for a time period, generally 30 days. It also scans the sleeping apps for permission reduction, since permissions of even sleeping apps can be exploited by malware.

Comment: But this doesn’t happen everyday? Wouldn’t that be something that happens daily in the background. This is the first time it’s ever happened.

Answer (score 0):

As explained in the comment, this is probably normal activity. Some games can take you to playstore from inside or via ads.

If you are worried then install a virus scanner. There are many free versions out there. I use kaspersky, paid version. But the free mode would be good enough.

Comment: I wasn’t playing a game at the time this happened. My only concern is the fact that this happened yesterday and has never happened before. I’ve had this phone for a good two years and never have I seen this pop up in my activity prior.